Decoding Versioned transaction
Versioned transaction are constructed and signed in frontend, and sent to BE, on BE i am trying to decode the instructions present in the compiled transaction, Any way to decode each instruction present in transaction?

Certainly! You can use VersionedTransaction.deserialize https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/107eec97b27c53b9055fc5f85718a31fe80c4890/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/versioned.ts#L79 followed by TransactionMessage.decompile on its message https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/107eec97b27c53b9055fc5f85718a31fe80c4890/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/message.ts#L35
That will give you each TransactionInstruction https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/107eec97b27c53b9055fc5f85718a31fe80c4890/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/legacy.ts#L87, which contains the accounts, program, and data
